# Javascript Email Validation Specific Domain

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to get someone to use a specific email domain of `@mail.fhsu.edu`. Here is my Validation code.

```
 function validateFHSUEmail(inputField, helpText) {
    if (inputField.value.length == 0) {
        if (helpText != null) {
            helpText.innerHTML = "Please Enter a Value";    
        }
        return false;
    } else {
        var reg = /^[a-z.]+@mail.fhsu.edu$/;
        if (!reg.test(inputField)) {
            if (helpText != null) {
            helpText.innerHTML = "Please Enter FHSU Email"; 
            }
```

Am I calling it wrong or what because no matter what it returns false.

Comment: FYI, you'll need to change any `.`s in your regex to `\.` - `.` is a special character meaning "any single character can match here".

Comment: @michaelb958 not inside a `[ ]` group but otherwise good catch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're testing the variable "inputField", which apparently is a reference to a DOM element. You want `inputField.value` in the test.

*edit* Note the comment wherein it's pointed out that your regex should use `\.` for the periods in the domain name.

Answer (score 0):

If you want valid email and specific domain try this regex:

```
/^(([^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@domain.com$/
```